# How to specify parameters such as "X dimension" and "Y dimension" using tc-lib-barcode

Tags: php, barcode, pdf417

I am working on an API with a company that requires us to generate a PDF417 barcode. In the documentation they sent us, they ask that we use the following settings:

```
XDim = 0.02
YDim = 0.03
Bar Height = 0.30
Aspect = 0.25
Columns = 16 or 18
Rows = 0
ECC = 4
Containment area is about 1000 X 5000 unit of pixels
```

According to the sole example in the documentation of [the tc-lib-barcode library I'm using](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode), these are the parameters I can work with:

```
// generate a barcode
$bobj = $barcode->getBarcodeObj(
    'QRCODE,H',                     // barcode type and additional comma-separated parameters
    'https://tecnick.com',          // data string to encode
    -4,                             // bar width (use absolute or negative value as multiplication factor)
    -4,                             // bar height (use absolute or negative value as multiplication factor)
    'black',                        // foreground color
    array(-2, -2, -2, -2)           // padding (use absolute or negative values as multiplication factors)
    )->setBackgroundColor('white'); // background color
```

As you can see, the company and tc-lib-barcode use different names for the parameters, or perhaps tc-lib-barcode just doesn't provide support for the parameters I need to change. There is nothing in the tc-lib-barcode documentation about "XDim", "YDim", etc. So I'm trying the map the specifications from the company to the parameters in the tc-lib-barcode documentation.

According to [the Wikipedia article on PDF417](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417):

> "The user can decide how wide the narrowest vertical bar (X dimension) is, and how tall the rows are (Y dimension)."

So perhaps `XDim` == `bar width`?

In `\src\Type\Square\PdfFourOneSeven.php`, I see:

```
 /**
     * Row height respect X dimension of single module
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $row_height = 2;
```

So I thought maybe `YDim` == `$row_height`. I changed $row_height to `.03` but then I got an error (`Undefined offset: 2` thrown by line 85 in `\src\Type\Raw.php`).

I seem to be going about this the wrong way and could really use some help. I have reached out to the company but they just tell me to buy one of 2 software packages that can produce a compatible barcode. The licenses are out of our budget and since PDF417 is an ISO standard, it shouldn't be impossible to produce a compatible barcode with virtually any software package.

I notice that in the first parameter of `getBarcodeObj`, you can pass "additional comma-separated parameters" but I see no documentation on what parameters, and in what order, you can pass there.

Comment: First you need to figure out what units they're asking for, and then you can figure out how to get your library to produce it.

Comment: @miken32 Could you elaborate? Supposing the unit they're asking for is millimeters. How would I go about it?

Comment: @JohnnyTisdale - We are looking for the same thing. I was wondering if you got the solution for it?